# Issue with my usage of project reactor or() operator

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I use **Project Reactor** and I have the following reactive chain:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(
            user -> validateUser(user)
                .or(validateEmailNotExists(user))
                .or(saveUser(user))
                .single()
        );
}
```

For some reason, the last `Mono`, i.e. `saveUser(user)` is empty an I get the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Source was empty
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RC1.jar:3.3.0.RC1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingleMono] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.single(Mono.java:3898)
    org.example.contracttestingdemo.handler.UserHandler.lambda$createUser$1(UserHandler.java:54)
```

Here is the code for the `saveUser` method:

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user)
        .flatMap(newUser -> status(CREATED)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(newUser))
        );
}
```

It is odd because when used without the `or().single()` operator, the `saveUser` method does return a non-empty result.

FYI, here is the repository:

```
UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long>...
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: By the way if I use the following chain (notice the `saveUser` call has been replaced by something more explicit and simple):

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(
            user -> validateUser(user)
                .or(validateEmailNotExists(user))
                .or(status(CREATED).body(BodyInserters.fromObject("something")))
                .single()
        );
}
```

the issue is still occurring indicating that even though a non-empty `Mono` is returned, my use of the `or()` operator is not working.

Comment: I have opened another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825533 related to this one but much more concise and easily reproducible.

Comment: VTC as a duplicate of your other question as the cause is the same - you want `switchOnEmtpy()` instead. If I've misunderstood for any reason, let me know and I'll take another look.