# Issue with Project Reactor's or() operator usage

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I would like to chain `Mono`s and emit the first non-empty of them. I thought the **`or()`** operator was designed for this purpose.

Here is my chain of `Mono`s: first one is empty and second one should emit "hello".

```
@Test
void orTest() {
    Mono<String> chain = Mono.<String>empty().or(Mono.just("hello"));

    StepVerifier.create(
        chain
    )
        .expectNext("hello")
        .verifyComplete();
}
```

However, I get the following failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(hello)" failed (expected: onNext(hello); actual: onComplete())
```

Can someone please help? What I am getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand `or()` - it takes the [first *result* emitted](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#or-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) from either publisher. That's very different from the first *item* emitted - if one of the `Mono` objects emits an `onComplete()` result without returning anything, then, as is happening in your case, you'll get that result with nothing emitted.

You can see this behaviour if you do something like `Mono.<String>empty().delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(100)).or(Mono.just("hello"));` instead, which will almost certainly pass (as the `onComplete()` result of the emtpy `Mono` is delayed sufficiently for the other `Mono` to emit an item first.)

However, the method you're after is [`switchIfEmpty()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-), which (as the name suggests) will wait for the first `Mono` to complete, then fallback to the second if the first returns an empty result:

```
@Test
public void orTest() {
    Mono<String> chain = Mono.<String>empty().switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("hello"));

    StepVerifier.create(chain)
            .expectNext("hello")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: Is this then a typo in the official documentation? It mentions a **result** and not a **signal**. See: *Emit the first available result from this mono or the other mono*

Comment: Thanks for this very clear explanation! It is much clearer to me now.

Comment: @balteo No, it was me mixing up the wording - sorry about that. Now fixed.

Comment: Umm... Is ***signal***  synonymous for ***result***?

Comment: @balteo Yup, pretty much as I understand it.

Comment: Great. Thanks again.